# How to display rectangle thumbnails for video in android

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

Hi all i want to display video thumbnail with rectangle shape as in given link .I have used some code and now video is displaying in thumbnail but not with rectangle as display in given link.So please suggest me, is this is possible in android or not .If possible then how..Thanks..
http://lh3.ggpht.com/_xBHTh_QdoYY/S81nyg57zsI/AAAAAAAAA2A/knYE08lHypU/video3e312550f115%5B15%5D.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to get the thumbnails-

```
Bitmap _bitmap = null;
            thumbnail = new ImageView(mContext);
            thumbnail.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            try {
                String path = "SOME PATH GOES HERE...";
                _bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                thumbnail.setImageBitmap(_bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                thumbnail.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
```

Comment: For that you need your custom layout which has a image i.e. thumbnail at the background and an ImageView at the center and on top of thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks Rajkiran,exactly this is the solution.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark it as accepted so that other people having same problem will get benefited.